# Does Brocard's conjecture require that there is always a prime number in the interval $(x-x^{\theta},x);\ \theta \le 0.5$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

In thinking about Brocard's conjecture, I have formulated an apparently necessary condition for its truth. **I have two questions:** First, is my reasoning sound; and second, have I simply rediscovered something which is already generally appreciated? If so, can anyone point me to relevant literature?

[Brocard's conjecture](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BrocardsConjecture.html), which is unproved but believed to be true, posits that for $n\ge 2$, the interval $(p_n^2,p_{n+1}^2)$ contains at least four prime numbers. I examine here a weaker conjecture, that an interval $(p_{k-1},p_k)$ contains at most one number which is the square of a prime. This is related to Brocard's conjecture in that if an interval $(p_{k-1},p_k)$ contained more than one prime squared, then those squares would define a subinterval bounded by the squares of primes but lacking any prime numbers, contrary to Brocard's conjecture.

Refinements to [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) establish that for sufficiently large $x$, the interval $[x-x^{\theta},x]$ contains at least one prime; currently, the established minimum numerical value is $\theta = 0.525$. Not all intervals between consecutive primes will contain the square of a smaller prime, but for those that do, we can state that for sufficiently large $p_n$,
$$p_n-p_n^{\theta}<p_{n-1}<p_k^2\le (p_n-4)$$
The $-4$ in the right hand term arises because $p_k^2$ has the form $6m+1$ and $p_n$ has the form $6m\pm 1$. It is fair to ask, can $p_{k-1}^2$ ever fall in the same interval? If so, then $p_n-p_n^{\theta}<p_{k-1}^2$.
$$p_{k-1}=p_k-2a\le \sqrt{(p_n-4)}-2a;\ a\in \mathbb Z_+\\ 
(p_{k-1})^2\le p_n-4-4a\sqrt{(p_n-4)}+4a^2\\ 
p_n-p_n^{\theta}<p_n-4-4a\sqrt{(p_n-4)}+4a^2$$
Assuming the most restrictive case $a=1$, that is where $p_{k-1}\text{ and } p_k$ are minimally distant from each other, the last statement can only be true if $p_n^{\theta}>4\sqrt{(p_n-4)}$. For large $p_n$, $\sqrt{(p_n-4)}\approx (p_n)^{0.5}$, whereupon the necessary condition becomes $p_n^{\theta-0.5}>4$. For $\theta = 0.525$ we obtain $p_n>2^{80}$. That is to say that if consecutive primes exist that bracket more than one prime number squared, those consecutive primes are larger than $2^{80}\approx 1.2 \times 10^{24}$.

It appears to me that for any ${\theta-0.5}>0$, there will always be some conceivable $p_n$ for which it is possible that two consecutive primes might bracket two prime squares, which is inconsistent with Brocard's conjecture. This leads me to speculate that Brocard's conjecture cannot be proved, and perhaps cannot be true, unless it is the case that there is always a prime number in the interval $(x-x^{\theta},x);\ \theta \le 0.5$. Is this reasonable, or have I gone off the rails somewhere?

Comment: Please give a reference to Brocard's conjecture.

Comment: @Jean Marie Link inserted in text.

Comment: Usually, we are looking for the gap from the given prime to the next prime, but it won't make much difference. The best known upper bound for prime gaps is almost surely extremely weak, but apparently an unconditional proof has not been found yet for anything better. Heuristics indicate that $p_{n+1}-p_n\le \ln^2(p_n)$ holds for $n\ge 5$ , where $p_n$ denotes the $n$ th prime.

Comment: @Peter I appreciate that gaps are usually looked at 'upwardly' but [Baker et al](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.360.3671&rep=rep1&type=pdf) report their result in the way posted, so I stuck with that. The thrust of my question is that some independent proof of Brocard might be leveraged to prove that in the format presented, $\theta \le 0.5$